# WPF canvas show popup command control like Word text

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

In my application, I am allowing user to select the shapes added in the canvas. When user select a particular shape in canvas then I want to show user control on top of the shape selected. The user control can be different for different shapes.
For ellipse shape I want to show UserControlEllipseProperties whereas for Rectangle shape I want to show UserControlRectangleProperties. This is something similar to what word is showing when text is selected in the Microsoft word application. A pop command control is shown with options related to text (like Bold, Italics, Underline, font etc.). User can move the mouse on that command control and click on those buttons.

How I can achieve this popping window?
[Microsoft word text properties flowing command control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iswSv.png)

Thanks,
S

I have tried with WPF popup control but I could not achieve similar behaviour which will show the draggable/movable user control in the UI till the shape is selected in the canvas and it will also allow user to click or select options (like textbox/combobox/buttons etc.) in the user control UI.